# LocalStorage data into Mongodb

Tags: javascript, html, database, mongodb, local-storage

I am totally new to mongoDb ,and I was wondering if there a way to store the localStorage data into mongoDb cluster?
Also can we use BOTH mongoDb and localStorage to store an applications data? I have made a small application(html-css-js) using localStorage to store the data now I was wondering if I can use mongoDb for user login and if it's a verified user I can redirect him to the localStorage run application.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are linking two incompatible concepts. "localStorage" is a simple client-side data storage in the browser. MongoDB is a server-side database. It cannot be accessed from the browser. If you need to save data from localStorage to a database, you should use your web server for this. The browser will make a request to your web server and your web server to save the necessary data in the database. Otherwise, you can store any data in localStorage or MongoDB